# Installing networkX in Sublime

Tags: python

I am really frustrated right now, how can I install networkx package in sublime? I have installed in in the python libary(mac), and I can import networkx code fine in terminal...but when I try to run the code in sublime, I only get this error:

```
import networkx as nx
```

File "/......my project path here", line 2, in 
    g = nx.Graph ()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't install networkX in sublime but install it to python, so the title should be changed

Because you have not given us information on how you installed it, we cannot be sure if you installed it correctly nor how you did it.
When you say 'installed it in the python library', i take that as you copied a .egg file into the dist-packages folder. So before trying my method, undo whatever you did before.

A easy way to install it, is to use easy_install

Open up your terminal, then paste this

```
sudo easy_install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/networkx/networkx-1.8.1.tar.gz#md5=b4a9e68ecd1b0164446ee432d2e20bd0
```

And you are done!

Now, try running your script again

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
When I run your command, I get this error: x-1.8: error: Can't download https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/networkx/networkx-1.8: 404 Not Found


I installed it through the terminal, used the install setup.py command.


I can run the same code through Python in terminal, just dont work in sublime.


When I run this code: import networkx 
networkx.test()
 in sublime, I get error, when I run it in Python (from terminal), it works.

Comment: If I run for example :import networkx 
networkx.Graph()

In sublime, I get: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'

Comment: Are you sure that you copied it right? In your error message you pasted in the comment did not show the whole link, the link is scrollable to the left! Building from source does the same thing anyway, so doesn't matter.
If you cannot run it in sublime but you can in the terminal, it's a high chance that you don't use the same python version in sublime as in your terminal.

Comment: By the way, I use SUBLIMEREPL (doesnt matter really, have tried with normal build).

But when I try to run the python shell in sublime, and write import networkx, I only get this error :AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'

Comment: Ye, just my fault, copied it wrong. I think you are right, sublime is actually using another python?!?

Comment: At least in my case it used the same python version, but since they don't execute in the same way something got to be different atleast.
If you want to know how sublime executes you python, check the Python.sublime-build file.
in linux it's located in ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Python/Python.sublime-build, not sure about mac though. It might be /Library/Application\ Support/Sublime-text-2/, but thats a guess.

I prefer to run my scripts in the terminal, but that's just a personal preference

Comment: This is pretty obvious, but i hope that you don't have a file or folder in your saved scripts directory named 'networkx', that messes  up the import and instead tries to import that folder/file

Comment: Ive checked,sublime uses the wrong python...How can I select my installed Python version??

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same error message.
My point was:

The name of my running file was **networkx.py** . If you **change your file nam**e then it will run.